# Tab bar disappear after segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

After reading few topics in stack overflow about this problem, maybe someone will find where is my mistake: The tab bar in the destination controller disappear.
My source view controller is a Table view controller. when clicking on the cell There is a segue to Navigation view controller that linked to the destination view controller.
The segue is modal.

Table View Controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"cell selected");

//doing some thing and call to the segue..

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromSearchToProfileSeg" sender:nil];
}
```

And the prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fromSearchToProfileSeg"]){
    ///searchVC.username = self.username;
    NavViewController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    ProfileViewController *pro = (ProfileViewController * )navigationController.topViewController;
    pro.username = self.username;

    }

}
```

And it's Look like:

[image]
Unfortunately, When clicking on the cell, the segue is working and the destination view controller is open, but the tab bar disappear. Does anyone know where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have the option "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" in the attributes inspector for that view controller.

[image]

Comment: Hide bottom bar on push is not selected

Comment: Where is you tab bar controller in the storyboard?